# What user.agent property does GWT use for IE7?

Tags: gwt, user-agent

I noticed there us no "user.agent" ie7 defined in GWT for permutation compilation.

If I want to have a specific implementation of a class for ie7 how could I define this?  If the user.agent is ie6 I will just use that user.agent as we do not support ie6.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ie6` is used for Internet Explorer 6 and 7. [UserAgent.gwt.xml](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml) lists the `user.agent` deferred binding properties defined by GWT.

Answer (score 0):

archvo/etc/git confg:system a git conig
~/.gitconfig file-global
_.gitconfig(c:\document and settings/$user

e macs-editor
$git config--global core.editor
herram d' diferenci

$git config--global merge.tool
vimdiff
compro config

$git config--list